# magento 2 print array in block function

Tags: magento2, php

I am using Magento 2. I made a small mistake unfortunately i am unable to find

**Index.php**

```
public function getBannerCollection(){
        $collection = $this->_bannerModel->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToSelect('*');
        return $collection;
    }
```

**phtml**

```
<?php $bannerCollection =  $block->getBannerCollection();
print_r($bannerCollection);?>
```

**error**

```
localhost:8080 is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

I made a small change but i can't find out can any one help me on this

But i can able to loop it

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution on this. we need to use `getData()`

```
$bannerCollection->getData();
```